# IP address not valid and dhcp not working

Tags: internet, connection

Guys I'm hoping to get answers to my problem which is I have a triangle on my internet and when I troubleshoot is says IP address configuration not valid so I searched up what to do on YouTube and they told me to write some ip stuff at protocol4, it worked but then it says dhcp not enabled I also searched that up on YouTube, they told me to obtain IP address automatically  in the local area protocol 4 and it worked but it told me that the IP configuration thing is not valid again. Please help me, I want to enjoy my computer, btw I'm wired Internet and Windows 7

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could upload screenshots of the error(s) you are getting, so we can see if they are relevant. Or copy the entire text of the error message over.  It is possible your internet connection is lost from time to time because of issues with your provider. In that case there is not much you can do. However, since you get some message telling you your IP address in invalid, it's possible an issue with your own network.  You can either assign your computer an IP-address manually, or you can enable DHCP, so your router will assign an IP-address automaticly to your PC.

Comment: Please first provide us with screenshots of the warning or error messages you are getting. They might provide us with more details, which can be useful to answer your question more precise.

Comment: My internet is working fine right now but when I get the error I'll take a screenshot

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you made changes to your router, if you don't value any configuration you may have made to the router, you can simply try a factory reset (router-specific, but generally involves holding down a small button with a pin on the back). Most routers come in a pretty deployable state in a home environment, which is obviously what we're doing here.

If you have changed configuration in your Windows 7 install, such as enforcing IP bindings (which isn't likely, since you're having DHCP issues), then you're on your own there. You'll probably want to tell Windows to basically find anything it can on its own -- it's just more sane for a home user to do this.

Good luck.

Comment: For some reason my computer has Internet for a while then for another while this issue comes up right now I have Internet but anyways I'm pretty sure I deleted something I shouldn't have when I was cleaning my computer because everytime I start my computer, it says _obij something something was not found so not sure what to do when I don't have Internet

Comment: @user5191 Admittedly, that's not enough information for me to go off of. Could you be more specific?

Also, hooray for a -1 on the potential answer because clearly someone else is offering something useful here. :/